# Standard duality argument

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In a paper of distributionally robust optimization, there is a step of derivation using the "standard duality argument". It obtains $ \sup _{\mathbb{Q}_{i} \in \mathcal{M}(\Xi)} \inf _{\lambda \geq 0}  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Xi} \ell(\xi) \mathbb{Q}_{i}(d \xi) +\lambda\left(\varepsilon-\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\| \mathbb{Q}_{i}(\mathrm{~d} \xi)\right)$ from
$\sup _{\mathbb{Q}_{i} \in \mathcal{M}(\Xi)} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Xi} \ell(\xi) \mathbb{Q}_{i}(\mathrm{~d} \xi)$
s.t. $\quad \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\| \mathbb{Q}_{i}(\mathrm{~d} \xi) \leq \varepsilon$.

It is confusing for me. Since if I try to use the strong duality, the optimal value of dual problem is solved from the minimax problem $\inf_{\lambda\ge 0}\sup_{\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{M}(\Xi) } \dots$. I am wondering how $\sup_{\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{M}(\Xi) } \inf_{\lambda\ge 0}$ is derived in their paper.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a "standard duality argument" in the sense that after using strong duality (which happened in a previous step), we usually turn parts of the objective function into constraints using this standard argument (which galton's answer explains).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not use strong duality in that step. The two expressions are equal because the infimum in the first expression is $-\infty$ when the constraint in the second expression is not satisfied, so the supremum operator ensures that the constraint is satisfied also in the first expression.

Comment: Great explanation! Many thanks for your answer. :D